# check activity of <input> element in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Please tell me how to replace document.addEventListener with react components

```
const searchIsActive = createRef()
const searchContainer = createRef()
    document.addEventListener('focusin', () => {
        searchContainer.current.style.background = "#303130";
    }
)

return(
    <div ref={ searchContainer } className="search__container">
    <img src="img"></img>
    <input ref={ searchIsActive } type="text"></input>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: no one course talked about onFocus or onBlur, all show examples on buttons with onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with two handlers [onFocus](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#onfocus) and [onBlur](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#onblur) with a single `ref` to your input wrapper:

```js
function App() {
  const searchContainer = React.createRef();

  const onFocusHandler = () => {
    searchContainer.current.style.background = "#303130";
  };

  const onBlurHandler = () => {
    searchContainer.current.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  };

  return (
    <div ref={searchContainer} className="search__container">
      <img src="img"></img>
      <input
        type="text"
        onFocus={onFocusHandler}
        onBlur={onBlurHandler}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```